# elixir like atoms in python?

Tags: python

I am building a project in python that requires the use of a small state machine. I could of course just make a bunch of states like

```
__StateOne__ = 0
__StateTwo__ = 1
__StateThree__ = 2
# etc
```

and then just keep track with something like state = _*StateOne*_, but I was hoping to be able to do something like [elixir style atoms](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-types.html#atoms). Would this be possible with some import or third party library?

Comment: Do you mean "atoms"? For what value of *"like"*? That is, which aspects of atoms' behaviour do you want? How about an enumerator (built into 3.4, available as a backport to earlier versions)?

Comment: errr sorry yes. atoms. I'm not sure why I keep saying atomic. an enumerator might work. do you have a link?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html (just saying, it's the top hit on Google for *"Python enumerator"*...)

Comment: I've come to find that just because its a top hit on google doesn't neccesarily make it a good one :p

Comment: It's also part of Python's documentation, which should have at least been a clue

Comment: Erlang/Elixir Atoms are by principle nothing more than: __stateX__ = 'stateX'. Its like a constant having itself as value. That way different machines will always have the same value for that atom/constant. I cant see why you would need atoms for your state machine, constants will work just fine. Using enumeration could also benefit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use enums:

```
from enum import Enum

states = Enum('<a descriptive name>', 'one two three four')
```

`states.one`, `states.two`, `states.three`... are now sorta like atoms, for your purposes.